# RabbitMQ - Reprioritize message already in queue

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, priority-queue

We are building spark based jobs. Processing each message delivered by the queue takes time. There is a need to be able to reprioritize one already sent to the queue.

I am aware there is priority queue implementation available, but not sure how to re-prioritize the existing message in the queue?

One bad workaround is to push that message again as higher priority, so that it handled on priority. Later drop the message with same content which had low or no priority when it's turns comes next.

Is there a natural way we can handle this situation or any other queues that supports scenario better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't. Queues are to be considered as lists of messages in flight. It is not possible to delete/update them.

Your approach of submitting a higher priority message is the only feasible solution.

RabbitMQ is a messaging system (such as the postal one), it is not a DataBase or a storage service. The storage in form of queues is a necessary feature as much as the postal service needs storage for postcards in transit. It is optimized for the purpose and does not allow to access the messages easily.